# Did the father in Missing (1982) feel he was to blame somewhat in real life?

Tags: historical-accuracy, missing

At the end of the movie, the American officials state that they are just protecting business interests, and that he was a businessman himself. Did the father in real life feel he was at least partially to blame for events, like if such an excuse was said in real life?

Comment: Based on [The Execution of Charles Horman: An American Sacrifice by Thomas Hauser](https://read.dukeupress.edu/hahr/article/60/3/560/149581/The-Execution-of-Charles-Horman-An-American)

Comment: Horman's father; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Horman